# How is Nigerian Standard English categorized?

Tags: english, dialects, prosody, varieties

From what I can tell, the only nontrivial difference between Nigerian Standard English and the catalog of commonly referenced dialects of English is that Nigerian Standard English has a different prosody, as it is syllable-timed as opposed to stress-timed.

I'm having a difficult time finding examples of dialects of a language with differing prosodic qualities. Given this, is Nigerian Standard English categorized as a discrete language, a dialect of English, or does it fall under some other category?

Comment: Alo and Mesthrie 'Nigerian English: morphology and syntax' (in ['A Handbook of Varieties of English'](http://books.google.com.au/books?hl=en&lr=&id=mtd3a-56ysUC&oi=fnd&pg=PR10&dq=nigerian+english&ots=HZDK1pZCyW&sig=kdHAVhdz4xe2Gg51ci0N8HE9OG8&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=nigerian%20english&f=false)) list quite a few nontrivial features of Nigerian English that make it different from other varieties.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a read (and my professor a good shaking).

Comment: Gaston, I'm not sure the book talks about Nigerian Standard English. Unless I'm missing something, all I can find is the entry on Nigerian Pidgin.

Comment: Alo and Mesthrie's article discussing the morphology and syntax of Nigerian English is at pp 813--827 of that book. The article that follows (pp. 828ff) discusses Nigerian Pidgin English. Also possibly of interest is this [paper](http://www.spectrum.uni-bielefeld.de/TAPS/Gut.pdf) by Ulrike Gut which explores the many differences Nigerian English and in British English in the area of prosody.

Comment: And re your professor: there is great variation in Nigerian English, from a variety termed a pidgin through to a variety that is very similar to British English. It may well be that prosody is a difference from British English that is shared by all varieties of Nigerian English.

Comment: @Andy Invite your professor to join us! And all of the colleagues too. :D

Answer (score 4):

To the question

> Is Nigerian Standard English categorized as a discrete language, a dialect of English, or does it fall under some other category?

the answer is: It is classified as a **variety** of English like British English, American English, or Australian English. All varieties of English have regional dialects and other kinds of lects and slangs.

Answer (score 3):

According to R. Hickey ( [Legacies of Colonial English. Studies in Transported Dialect.](https://www.google.ru/imgres?imgurl=http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q%3Dtbn:ANd9GcTIIsuc_89ZjaRz-KybnZ0hNTbw8Oj5xCA6ApyG2o1hqwgU0k29&imgrefurl=https://books.google.com/books/about/Legacies_of_Colonial_English.html?id%3D30o5SwAACAAJ%26source%3Dkp_cover&h=648&w=432&tbnid=yToYyS7Q1b0rnM:&tbnh=160&tbnw=106&usg=__AowocUEPy_RmY8uaHnzHn9UZySU%3D&vet=10ahUKEwiQxbmL-5vYAhVBOJoKHf71Am8Q_B0IjQEwCg..i&docid=BdWFhq17YEFMaM&itg=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQxbmL-5vYAhVBOJoKHf71Am8Q_B0IjQEwCg)), the Nigerian English, as most other African Englishes, should be classified as a part of common meta-cluster merged together with South-Eastern Asian Englishes (pp. 510-522).

On the other hand, if we pay closer attention to [Kachru's Asian Englishes; Beyond the Canon](https://cup.columbia.edu/book/asian-englishes-beyond-the-canon/9789622096660)( e. g. at p.14 of the 2005's copy) we can easily notice that the issue of classification for world Englishes is still open.